# Missing Dependency Errors when Installing OpenVas Server

Tags: yum, rhel5, dependencies, openvas

I'm trying to install OpenVAS on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.5. I've successfully run yum install openvas-client, but yum install openvas-server prints the following errors:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
openvas-client-3.0.1-1.el5.art.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libopenvas_hg.so.3 is needed by package openvas-client-3.0.1-1.el5.art.i386 (installed)
openvas-client-3.0.1-1.el5.art.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libopenvas_nasl.so.3 is needed by package openvas-client-3.0.1-1.el5.art.i386 (installed)
openvas-client-3.0.1-1.el5.art.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libopenvas_omp.so.3 is needed by package openvas-client-3.0.1-1.el5.art.i386 (installed)
openvas-scanner-3.2-0.2.el5.art.i386 from atomic has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: net-snmp-utils is needed by package openvas-scanner-3.2-0.2.el5.art.i386 (atomic)
openvas-client-3.0.1-1.el5.art.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libopenvas_misc.so.3 is needed by package openvas-client-3.0.1-1.el5.art.i386 (installed)
openvas-scanner-3.2-0.2.el5.art.i386 from atomic has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: openldap-clients is needed by package openvas-scanner-3.2-0.2.el5.art.i386 (atomic)
openvas-client-3.0.1-1.el5.art.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libopenvas_base.so.3 is needed by package openvas-client-3.0.1-1.el5.art.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: net-snmp-utils is needed by package openvas-scanner-3.2-0.2.el5.art.i386 (atomic)
Error: Missing Dependency: libopenvas_base.so.3 is needed by package openvas-client-3.0.1-1.el5.art.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: libopenvas_hg.so.3 is needed by package openvas-client-3.0.1-1.el5.art.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: libopenvas_nasl.so.3 is needed by package openvas-client-3.0.1-1.el5.art.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: openldap-clients is needed by package openvas-scanner-3.2-0.2.el5.art.i386 (atomic)
Error: Missing Dependency: libopenvas_omp.so.3 is needed by package openvas-client-3.0.1-1.el5.art.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: libopenvas_misc.so.3 is needed by package openvas-client-3.0.1-1.el5.art.i386 (installed)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.
```

Notice that each of the missing dependencies is followed by the words (installed) or the words (atomic) - for the name of the repository. When I try to install any of these sub-dependencies, the installation fails (either due to missing dependencies or since the rpm is already installed). For example, if I try to install a rpm for "libopenvas_hg.so.3", I get an error message indicating that it is already installed. Yet "libopenvas_hg.so.3" is listed as a missing dependency. Why? Do I need to uninstall all of the "missing" dependences first?

Answer (score 0):

As a guess...

I would say that the version of the openvas-scanner that you are trying to install; openvas-scanner-**3.2-0.2**.el5.art.i386 is different from your currently installed client; openvas-client-**3.0.1-1**.el5.art.i386

So yum is trying to install some dependencies for the scanner, which conflict with the installed dependencies used by the client. This is forcing yum to try to upgrade everything at once to meet requirements - including openvas-client. Hence why yum is telling you about your already installed openvas-client dependencies.

However... The fact that openldap-clients and net-snmp-utils are listed is suggesting a missing distro repo problem... openldap-clients is an un-versioned dependency from your base installs "updates" repo, so it should be resolved from that. This might indicate that you have disabled your rhel-updates repo, or that your subscription has expired.

try the following to see why you can't install the openldap-clients;

```
# yum info openldap-clients
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, fastestmirror, security
...
Available Packages
Name       : openldap-clients
Arch       : x86_64
Version    : 2.3.43
```

if that doesn't work try;

```
yum --enablerepo=base  --enablerepo=updates info openldap-clients
```

and then try

```
yum --enablerepo=base  --enablerepo=updates install openldap-clients net-snmp-utils
```

Basically, its starting with resolving your distro dependencies, and then see if openvas-scanner still can't update...